# Run an HTTP Server on another sub process

Tags: node.js

Assume that I have a js file that has a timer and in the timer callbacks, I want to create an HTTP Server in a random port.

Well, How can I create HTTP servers in a child or sub process in nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have a sub process you can run as many webserver as you want on a single process.
If you really want to do so, have a look a the cluster module, for example: http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_cluster

Comment: I know that, but really I need to do this. Thanks for suggesting `cluster`, is there any more solution?

Comment: other ways would be to fork and create the server in the son process. I don't really see why you want to do that. What could also be done is have a pull for slave process and a master sending port to slave on which to create the server. If this can be done with cluster this would be the easier way other wise you would have to look at in process communication with something like http://zerorpc.dotcloud.com for example.

Comment: What I just describe is actually what cluster brings in an nicely wrap module.